# Layer is not supported (When train Keras model trained with QAT)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

When I trained a Keras model using QAT (Quantization aware training),

There are some non-compatible problems like not support BatchNormalization, or UpSampling2D, etc.

How to prevent it directly without apply each layer with tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_annotate_layer on each layer? (especially when building model with tensorflow keras functional API (instead of tf.keras.Sequential))

Answer (score 2):

Supported layers for QAT module can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/model-optimization/blob/0f6dd5aeb818c5f61123fc1d5642435ea0f5cd70/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/core/quantization/keras/default_8bit/default_8bit_quantize_registry.py#L72)

Then, to quantize some layers instead of whole Model, just followed the official [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/quantization/training_comprehensive_guide#quantize_some_layers), then add what layer you wanna use to quantize.

```py
#added layers here
supported_layers = [tf.keras.layers.Conv2D, tf.keras.layers.Dense, tf.keras.layers.ReLU]

def apply_quantization_to_dense(layer):
  for supported_layer in supported_layers:
    if isinstance(layer, tf.keras.layers.Dense):
      return tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_annotate_layer(layer)
  return layer
```